# Python Z3 solver not correctly reporting satisfiability for exponent constraints

Tags: python, constraints, z3, solver, exponent

I noticed the [Z3 Solver library](https://pypi.org/project/z3-solver/) for python wasn't correctly reporting satisfiability for a problem involving exponents that I was working on. Specifically, it reported finding no solutions on cases where I knew a valid one -- unless I added constraints that effectively "told it the answer".

I simplified the problem to isolate it. In the code below, I'm asking it to find `q` and `m` such that `q^m == 100`. With the constraint `0 <= q < 100`, you have, of course, `q=10, m=2`.  But with the code below, it reports finding no solution (`raise Z3Exception("model is not available")`):

```py
import z3.z3 as z

slv = z.Solver()

m = z.Int('m')
q = z.Int('q')
slv.add(100 == (q ** m))
slv.add(q >= 0)
slv.add(q < 100)
slv.add(m >= 0)
slv.add(m <= 100)
slv.check()
```

However, if you replace `slv.add(m <= 100))` with `slv.add(m <= 2)` (or `slv.add(m == 2)`!), it has no problem finding the solution (of `q=10, m=2`).

1. Am I using Z3 wrong somehow?
2. I thought it would only report unsatisfiability ("model is not available") if it proved there was no solution and would otherwise hang while searching for a solution. Is that wrong? I didn't expect to be in a position where it only finds the solution if you shrink down the search space enough.

I haven't had this problem with any other operation besides exponentiation (e.g. addition, modulo, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misinterpreting what z3 is telling you. Change your line:

```
slv.check()
```

to:

```
print(slv.check())
print(slv.reason_unknown())
```

And you'll see it prints:

```
unknown
smt tactic failed to show goal to be sat/unsat (incomplete (theory arithmetic))
```

So, z3 doesn't know if your problem is `sat` or `unsat`; so you cannot ask for a model. The reason for this is the power operator: It introduces non-linearity, and the theory of non-linear integer equations is undecidable in general. That is, z3's solver is incomplete for this problem. In practice, this means z3 will apply a bunch of heuristics, and will hopefully solve the problem for you. But you can get `unknown` as well, as you observed.

It's not surprising that if you add extra constraints you're helping the solver and thus it finds an answer. You're just helping it further and those heuristics have an easier time. With different versions of z3, you can observe different behavior. (i.e., in the future, they might be able to solve this problem out-of-the-box, or maybe the heuristics will get worse and you helping it this way won't resolve the issue either.) Such is the nature of automatic-theorem proving with undecidable theories.

Bottom line: Any call to `check` can return `sat`, `unsat`, or `unknown`. Your program should check for all three possibilities and interpret the output accordingly.

Comment: Thanks so much! This was very helpful -- I didn't know about how unsat and unknown merge to the same exception. I had been assuming otherwise the whole time!